# Embedded/iframe always full height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm embedding several html files, these vary in "height". I want the embedded content to always fill out the parent div, so that I can scroll the parent instead of the embedded content.

If i set a specific height to the content-wrapper, which is larger than the embedded content's height, it works. The only problem is that because the content varies, the specific height won't match the other embedded html-files, and will leave a lot of dead space. How can I go about making the content-wrapper scale to the embedded content height?

```
<body onload="mathSubject()">
  <div class="nav">
      
  </div>
    
  <div class="content-wrapper">
      <embed id="embedded-content" type="text/html" src="content.html">
  </div>
</body>
```

```
.content-wrapper{
    width: 80vw;
    height: 90vh;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#embedded-content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I tried setting the height of both the embedded content, and content wrapper to 100% or auto, neither works.

Comment: You can try using the CSS `flex` property to make the content-wrapper scale to the embedded content height. Add the following CSS to your code:
`.content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#embedded-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;`
This will make the content-wrapper a flex container and set its direction to the column. The `align-items: stretch` property will make the embedded content stretch to fill the height of the container, and `flex-grow: 1` will make the embedded content take up any remaining space in the container.

Comment: @Sullivan Thank you but it doesn't work. The content-wrapper height is still not basing its height of the embedded-contents height.

Comment: To fix the issue where the content-wrapper height is not based on the embedded-contents height, you can try using the display: flex property on the content-wrapper element and setting its flex-direction to column. Then, set the embedded-contents element to have a flex-grow property of 1 to fill the remaining space in the content-wrapper element. This should allow the content-wrapper element to adjust its height based on the height of the embedded-contents element.

Comment: @Sullivan I understand what you're saying and you're not wrong. The only problem is when the embedded contents height is larger than the height of the container, the #embedded-content becomes scrollable. I need to be able to scroll with the parent.

Now the embedded-html file fills the container, but the container only fills 90vh, which means I scroll the embedded content. Now if I set a specific height to #embedded-content, which is greater than the height of its content, it works. But this is not usable, because I now need to set a specific height to each embedded document.

Comment: @Sullivan Let me try explaining it like this: Lets say I embedd the same content three times, each has a height greater than 100vh. And the containers width is 80vw. Now when I scroll, I scroll each item seperatly and scoll the parent. I want these embedded links to fill out the container, so now when I scroll the parent, I scroll them all. I hope you understand what I mean...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by using javascript to set the height of the iframe to the height of its content, using this site: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/automatically-adjust-iframe-height-according-to-its-contents-using-javascript.php

```
<style>
iframe{
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
</style>

<iframe src="demo.php" id="myIframe"></iframe>

<script>
// Selecting the iframe element
var iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");

// Adjusting the iframe height onload event
iframe.onload = function(){
    iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please add the code in your answer, not only the link.